# Alternatives to functors in F#

Tags: f#, functor

I would like to write the following:

```
module A =
  type Token 
  let foo Token = 

module B =
  type Token 
  let foo Token = 

let run (m : module) =
  m.B
  |> m.foo
```

basically a function that's generic in the module. Is there a way to do this in F#?

Comment: So am I understanding this right?  You basically want an overloaded function overloaded on the module?

Comment: yes, you can do this with functors in ML, but I was wondering if there's some alternative baked into F# since they decided not to support functors

Comment: I think types implementing an interface is the closest you're going to get.

Comment: There's no direct replacement, but if you could give a more realistic example of what you want to do it would help people give you useful alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

As kvb pointed out in a comment, it is hard to give an answer without a realistic example, because the best approach will depend on what you're actually trying to do.

In this trivial example, I would probably use F# interface to represent `Token` and add `Foo` as a member. Assuming that `Foo` returns an `int`, you can write the definition like this:

```
type Token = 
  abstract Foo : unit -> int
```

Then you can implement different tokens either using classes (which is quite heavyweight) or using object expressions. For example:

```
let tok = { new Token with
              member x.Foo () = 42 }
```

The code that corresponds to your `run` function is just a call of the `Foo` member: `tok.Foo()`